# Уезжает таблица при объединении HTML

Tags: html, html5, table, таблицы

Есть 2 таблицы.

В первом случае, используя "линейки", выходит то, что нужно:

[image: Таблица 1]

```css
td { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a2be2; padding: .5em 1em; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>6</td>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>8</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="3">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td rowspan="6">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="4">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td rowspan="3">1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>6</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>8</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Но, убрав эти "линейки", уезжает вправо:

[image: Таблица 2]

```css
td { box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #8a2be2; padding: .5em 1em; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="3">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
    <td rowspan="6">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="4" rowspan="4">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">1</td>
    <td rowspan="2">3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">1</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">3</td>
    <td rowspan="2">4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
    <td colspan="2">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Как можно это исправить, не добавляя пустые `<tr>`?